# No value given for one or more required parameters on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

this is my first time code on c# and MySQL i am sorry if my code is messy

My database is from Ms Access and i am trying to migrate all of the data into the MySQL workbench through c# application

below is my code

```
sqlcomm = "SELECT Product_Name,Product_ID,Product_Category,Quantity,Location,Manufacturer,Remark,QR_Code,Description,MinQuantity,Color_Type,Owner,Project_Name FROM Inventory_Management ";
            adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcomm, conn);
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter1);
            dt1.Reset();
            adapter1.Fill(dt1);
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt_Tbl = new DataTable();
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Product_Name");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Product_ID");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Product_Category");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Quantity");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Location");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Manufacturer");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Remark");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("QR_Code");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Description");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("MinQuantity");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Color_Type");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Owner");
                dt_Tbl.Columns.Add("Project _Name");
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    DataRow r = dt1.Rows[i];

                    DataRow dr;
                    dr = dt_Tbl.NewRow();
                    dr = r;
                    dt_Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

                    //string crd = r["Product_Name"].ToString();
                    //list.Add(r["Product_ID"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Product_Category"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Quantity"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Location"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Manufacturer"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Remark"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["QR_Code"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Description"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["MinQuantity"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Color_Type"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Owner"].ToString());
                    //list.Add(r["Project _Name"].ToString());
                }

                conn.Close();

                return dt_Tbl;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

am i missing something in the code?
any help would be appreciated

Thanks so much

Comment: Which line gives the error? What is the exact exception message?

Comment: it does not show the exception message , the program just start compile without giving any error. So i use a breakpoints to check code line by line. And the error pop out at "catch (Exception ex)" with the message said "No Value given for one or more required parameter"

Comment: _"it does not show the exception message"_ -> Remove the try/catch, or step through the code using the debugger to find out which line the exception comes from?

Comment: After following your advice , the exception is at "SELECT Product_Name,Product_ID,Product_Category,Quantity,Location,Manufacturer,Remark,QR_Code,Description,MinQuantity,Color_Type,Owner,Project_Name FROM Inventory_Management ";. Saying no value given for one or more required parameter. I think the problem is within my database as some of the column does not have any data in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the data from MS Access and creating a DataTable and loading it with the data. Now you need to write the Data Table (dt_Tbl) to MySQL database. So you need to open a connection to MySQL and run an insert command on it or use data adapter to push data to it.

You can clean up the code a bit by writing functions. Don't try to do too much in one function.

```
DataTable products = ReadProductsFromMSAccess();
WriteProductsToMySQL(products);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input , i managed to compile it  after some few debugging!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy Coding!